# Getting `Cannot find module '.next\server\pages-manifest.json'` error when trying to add `babel.config.js` in nextjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, next.js

I was trying to set up testing for my existing next app. We installed `jest`, `babel-jest` `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/preset-react` and, `react-test-renderer` and then created `babel.config.js`. When I remove this file, everything works fine.

As soon as I add the `babel.config.js` file, I get this error

```
Cannot find module '.next\server\pages-manifest.json'
```

The content of `babel.config.js` file is

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `next.js` you need to use `next/babel` preset as shown below

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@next/babel'],
};
```